# get previous value to the current value

Tags: r, dplyr

How can i get the previous value of each group in a new column `C` and the starting value for each group will be empty as it does not have previous value of respective group!

Can dplyr can perform this?

Code:

```
df <- data.frame(A = c('a1','a1','b1','b1','b1','c2','d2','d2'),
                B = c("2017-02-20","2018-02-14","2017-02-06","2017-02-27","2017-02-29","2017-02-28","2017-02-09","2017-02-10"))
```

Dataframe:

```
A       B         
a1   2017-02-20
a1   2018-02-14 
b1   2017-02-06
b1   2017-02-27 
b1   2017-02-29 
c2   2017-02-28
d2   2017-02-09
d2   2017-02-10
```

Expected Output

```
A       B         C
a1   2017-02-20
a1   2018-02-14 2017-02-20
b1   2017-02-06
b1   2017-02-27 2017-02-06
b1   2017-02-29 2017-02-27
c2   2017-02-28
d2   2017-02-09
d2   2017-02-10 2017-02-09
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `lag` function from `dplyr`:

```
df <- data.frame(A = c('a1','a1','b1','b1','b1','c2','d2','d2'),
                 B = c("2017-02-20","2018-02-14","2017-02-06",
                       "2017-02-27","2017-02-29","2017-02-28",
                                    "2017-02-09","2017-02-10"))


library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(A) %>% 
  mutate(C = lag(B, 1, default = NA))
```

This will apply the lag function for each group of "A"

Output:

```
# A tibble: 8 x 3
# Groups:   A [4]
  A     B          C         
  <fct> <fct>      <fct>     
1 a1    2017-02-20 NA        
2 a1    2018-02-14 2017-02-20
3 b1    2017-02-06 NA        
4 b1    2017-02-27 2017-02-06
5 b1    2017-02-29 2017-02-27
6 c2    2017-02-28 NA        
7 d2    2017-02-09 NA        
8 d2    2017-02-10 2017-02-09
```